# find the volume of the solid bounded by the surface

Tags: calculus, integration

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3 = a^6 \sin^{2}(\frac{\pi z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}})$$

i tried spherical coordinate system $$x = r\cos\phi \cos\psi,\, y = r\sin\phi \cos\psi,\, z = r\sin\psi$$
so i got $$r = a \cdot \sqrt[3]{\sin(\pi \sin\psi)}$$ and $$0\leq \sqrt[3]{\sin(\pi \sin\psi)}$$ when $$0 \leq \psi \leq \pi$$
also $$0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$$
$$|J| = r^2\cos\psi$$
finally i tried to solve the integral but it was equal to zero.
What's wrong with my argumenting?

Comment: $-\pi/2 \leqslant \psi \leqslant \pi/2$: the $cos$ shall remain positive

Answer (score 1):

I think you flipped spherical coordinates. You let $z = r\sin\psi$ and $0\leq\psi\leq\pi$, this means that $r\geq 0$. Correct way of doing this is $$z =r\cos\psi $$ and change the corresponding parts in $x$ and $y$ too.

Comment: $z=r \sin\psi$ is one of the ways to use spherical coordinates, and is correct provided that $-\pi/2 \leqslant \psi \leqslant \pi/2$